# Discord.py Which packages am missing?

Tags: discord, discord.py

The imports that i have:

```
import discord
import discord.ext.commands

from discord.ext import typed_commands

from discord.ext import commands
import discord.utils 
import config

from discord.ext import commands
from discord_buttons_plugin import *

import youtube_dl

from discord.ext.commands import bot
from discord import Game
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 8, in
>
> from discord.ext import commands
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 2, in

Context: I installed nextcord but when i removed it displays that error, is it normal?

Comment: Discord.py  has been discontinued so if you are looking to use nextcord, your title is misleading

Comment: I use to use discord py, but i installled nextcord because of this video, after i removed all it didnt work:
https://youtu.be/W2TcxVNctw8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommend using pycord if you are already familiar with dpy.
Instal through pip by doin:
`pip uninstall discord -y`
and
`pip install py-cord`

Comment: Right now i have files with code on it, if i install this do i need to fix the code?

Comment: Mostly would stay the same, the initialisation may need to change
Here is the [Documentation](https://docs.pycord.dev/)
Here are some [examples](https://github.com/Pycord-Development/pycord/tree/master/examples)